# How to fast search a string in a Excel file

Tags: java, excel

I am writing a JAVA program to search a string in a Excel file and extract the row which contains this certain string. I found all the related methods are looking all the rows one by one, and use .contain() method to tell whether this row contain the string or not. But the problems are:

a. There are large amount of strings to match.

b. The Excel files are very very large.

So I am curious about is there anyway to quickly search the string in a Excel file without iterating each line? Thanks a lot!

Comment: In VBA, one would read the entire range into an array (single step, very fast), and then iterate through the array, probably using `For Each ...`  with `Instr` to look for the existence of the string.  One could also use the `Range.Find` method, but that might be slower with very large files.  Is there something equivalent you can use in JAVA?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you, but i have not found it......

Answer (score 0):

Search algorithms in general have a performance of *O(n)* on a not presorted list. If there is no information given about the Excel file you are searching in, there is no algorithm with a better worst-case performance than *O(n)*.

So, that means, iterating over each line until the derised line(s) is found is necessary, no matter what. If you want to improve performance, you can try to use parallelization, for instance *MapReduce*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce